# In a tree, is there always a sink where every longest path ends in?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $T$ be an undirected tree. Can we always find a leaf vertex $s$ such that every longest path of $T$ has its other endpoint in $s$? It's easy to see that every longest path passes through the center of $T$. However, it is of course not true that there is a longest path between any two arbitary leaves.

Here's an example, where every longest path ends in $6$.

[image: example]

Maybe this could be shown by contradiction. So one could suppose there is no such "sink" leaf $s$. Then there is longest path starting at $v$, not ending in $s$. Can this be extended to a proof? Is there a simpler argument?

Comment: What if 6 were instead connected to 4?

Comment: If 6 was connected to 4, that would be fine too. Then the paths would be of length 2, and each one of them would end in say 6, or any other leaf vertex.

Comment: @BobWhiz You'd have 1-4-6 and 2-4-5 as paths of maximal length, hence no candidate for a "sink".

Answer (score 1):

What if you removed 6 from your graph? Can you find two longest paths that have no common endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're asking *does every longest path have leaf nodes as endpoints?*  The answer is yes.

If not, an endpoint $x$ of a longest path $P$ has two neighbours $u$ and $v$.  If $u$ is not in the path $P$, then we can add $u$ to $P$ to make a longer path (and similarly for $v$).  Thus $u$ and $v$ both belong to $P$.  But this gives a cycle, contradicting that the graph is a tree.

This is illustrated below:

[image]

Comment: I believe that the OP is asking whether every graph has an leaf that is a common endpoint for every longest path.

Comment: I thought that too until the OP responded to my question.  The comment "or any other leaf vertex" makes me think what I have here is the actual question.